# Find-move-replace files from /folder1 to /folder1/sub-folders

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, files, scripts, mv

Situation: folder1 have about 2000 files, folder2 have over 300 sub-folders and each sub-folder have 500 files. What I'm asking is to move/replace files from `/folder1` to `/folder2/sub-folders`, but only duplicates that are identified by digits, all files start `Aaaaaaaa.bbb -`.
Also all others file should stay in place.

```
/folder1   
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000125 tag tag_tag 9tag  
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002 tag tag_tag 9tag  
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0004207 tag tag_tag 9tag  
/folder2/sub-folders  
 /sub1  
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000125 tag tag_tag 9tag  
  Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000935 tag tag_tag 9tag  
 /sub2  
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002 tag tag_tag 9tag  
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0004207 tag tag_tag 9tag  
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000979 tag tag_tag 9tag
```

Ignore tags, they are different in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but you could do something like this:

Let's say you're in a directory in which you've folders folder1 and files A, B and A123, A456, A789.

You can move a file using the command:

```
mv A folder1
```

This moves file A to folder1

```
mv A* folder1
```

This moves files A123, A456 and A789 to folder1.

If you want to move those files to a subfolder of folder1, let's say subfolder1, just do:

```
mv A* folder1/subfolder1
```

Comment: folder1 have about 2000 files, folder2 have over 300 sub-folders and each sub-folder have 500 files. What I'm asking is to move/replace files from `/folder1` to `/folder2/sub-folders`, and names are not identical, only part of it `Aaaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002`