# Find duplicates by filemane

Tags: scripts, delete, filename, duplicate-files

I have about 167k files in single folder(for now) and renamed by this script in here: [Renaming bunch of files, but only part of the title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686794/renaming-bunch-of-files-but-only-part-of-the-title) .
How can I find duplicate files by their names (only digits in that specific spot) and delete oldest file:
`Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000125 tag tag_tag 9tag
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002 tag 9tag
Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002 tag tag_tag 9tag`

All tools that I used didn't provide such functionality so only script can help.

Comment: So `Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002 tag 9tag` would be a duplicate of `Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000002 tag tag_tag 9tag` because of `0000002`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: So, what defines the name? Will it always be in the format of `foo.bar - XXX` and the name is `foo`? Will there always be an extension? Will the space before the `-` always be the first space in the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Below here's a `find`, `sort` and `awk` one-liner.

Basic idea is to list files, sort them numerically (which works, unless Aaaaaaa.bbb and tags are themselves are numbers), and then let awk store each 3rd field of filenames into `prev` variable, and compare it with current value of field 3. If they match, print a message.

```
find . -type f -print | sort --numeric | awk '{if(prev == $3) print $0" is duplicate of "$prevEntry}{ prev=$3; prevEntry=$0}'
```

Below is a small demo:

```
    $ seq 6 10 | xargs printf "%07d\n" | xargs -I {} touch "Aaaaaaa.bbb - {} tag 9tag" 

    $ seq 00001 00020 | xargs printf "%07d\n" | xargs -I {} echo "Aaaaaaa.bbb - {} tag tag_tag 9tag"

$ find . -type f -print | sort --numeric | awk '{if(prev == $3) print $0" is duplicate of "$prevEntry}{ prev=$3; prevEntry=$0}'

    ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000006 tag tag_tag 9tag is duplicate of ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000006 tag tag_tag 9tag
    ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000007 tag tag_tag 9tag is duplicate of ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000007 tag tag_tag 9tag
    ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000008 tag tag_tag 9tag is duplicate of ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000008 tag tag_tag 9tag
    ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000009 tag tag_tag 9tag is duplicate of ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000009 tag tag_tag 9tag
    ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000010 tag tag_tag 9tag is duplicate of ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000010 tag tag_tag 9tag
```

Comment: It did great job on finding and listing dups, the same result I got from your last one-liner(finding gaps, set from `> 15` to `< 1`). The problem is not finding dups, but eliminating them, deleting old files and leaving new ones by creation (download) date.

Comment: @Ceslovas Ah, I missed that part when I was reading the question . . .OK. I'll try to see what I could do there and edit my answer once I have a solution

Comment: @Ceslovas Can you please do me a favor. Select two duplicate files that my command above has outputed , and run ` stat --format=%Y  FILENAME`  on each one separately, and let me know if the files have same output number

Comment: It's identical, and I double checked it

Comment: @Ceslovas how about if we replace %Y with  %Z option ?

Comment: Last three digits differs from each other.

Comment: One last test, `date +%s -r  FILENAME`

Comment: Also, if two files have same modification date, which file you'd prefer to keep ?

Comment: Identical and the same result as  with `stat --format=%Y`

Comment: I prefer the one which been created/downloaded the latest. The newer file. Don't know if that helps.

Comment: The problem is that the both commands that give you identical result are testing for modification date . . . Cannot seem to find easy way to test for creation date. I'll keep on looking , will let you know if I find anything

Comment: Any progress on solving this problem? Can this script in [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/470166/462277) help you?

Comment: @Ceslovas problem is, terdon's answer that you've linked is for ext4 only . I don't think it will work for ntfs . . .As for ntfs,  Ubuntu does come with some utilities, like `ntfsinfo`, but I haven't had luck with them so far, I kept getting errors.  Would there be any alternative way to differentiate newer files besides the date ? Like the specific contents of the files ?

Comment: Well, then lets do [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/693625/find-move-replace-files-from-folder1-to-folder1-sub-folders), but with one exception that there are no sub-folders in `/folder2`, and `/folder1` contains all newest files by date.  As for specifics only name differs (all tag part). For now I can manage dups manually one-by-one in windows, as now there are not so much. Will this alternative be good enough?

Comment: @Ceslovas  OK, but I don't quite understand why you need to move files in those folders. If everything in `folder2` is a duplicate of some  `folder1` contents, why not just delete `folder2` ? Or there are files you want to keep ?  Also , since you already have 22 rep on site, you should be able to join [askubuntu chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) . extended discussions comments aren't quite welcome here